# "OnlyShowIn" and "NotShowIn" not being obeyed in Openbox session?

Tags: .desktop, openbox

I'm running an Openbox session in Lubuntu 13.04 with the same `lxpanel` as I do in a standard Lubuntu session because I prefer that rather than the "right-click" menu provided in the Openbox session.

I notice that lxpanel's Menu lists some applications twice in an Openbox session but just once in a Lubuntu session. Digging a little more, I get the impression it is because the "OnlyShowIn" and "NotShowIn" instructions in certain .desktop files (in `/usr/share/applications`) are being ignored in an Openbox session.

For example, I have two "Software & Updates" .desktop files:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   466 Jun  7 00:51 software-properties-gnome.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   531 Jun  7 00:51 software-properties-gtk.desktop
```

The upper one has `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;`
and the lower one has `NotShowIn=GNOME;`

Both are visible in an Openbox session but only the latter appears, and correctly so, in a Lubuntu session. Is it because an Openbox session isn't a "desktop environment" and is not listed in [Registered OnlyShowIn Environments](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apb.html)?

(It's not just about GNOME. I also have two Synaptic Package Manager .desktop files; one has `OnlyShowIn=KDE;` it is visible in the Openbox session but is not seen in the Lubuntu session.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following page provides a good explanation of Openbox's autostart process, which is independent of the autostart you would experience with "registered" desktop environments:

http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/autostart-applications-in-openbox-3-5/

Note that the python-xdg package, required for Openbox to process desktop entries in /etc/xdg/autostart, is not installed by default with Openbox 3.5.0.  Also, the OnlyShowIn value for Openbox is rendered in all caps.

Good luck, and may your box always be open.

Comment: Thank you! I had read that a while ago but didn't realise its implication. Your answer has made it clear. Re. `python-xdg`, it's part of lubuntu-core and severals other desktops.

Answer (score 1):

LXpanel [looks](http://lxde.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=lxde/lxpanel;a=blob;f=src/menu-policy.c;hb=HEAD) at the variable "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" to display the menu entries. You can set the value of this variable to LXDE to achieve what you ask (`XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE lxpanel`), because if you set it to OPENBOX several menu entries do not appear.